# What is the best architecture to use at the back end for a java client based client/server setup?

Tags: java, php, sql, database, nosql

I'm fairly new to programming and have been focussing a great deal on Java in recent months. I would like to write an application with a Java applet front end which will capture information about my users and allow for them to be organised for sporting events. This seems to lend itself very nicely to the object orientated approach (e.g. each user is an object, each event is an object, each coach is an object, etc.).

However, my users will all need to access and make changes to the data stored as objects. A database of some sort seems to be called for but I only really have experience with RDBMS and I can't see how that maps to an object based front end. I could just use PHP driven HTTP calls but that would mean translating objects into tables and that feels like a move away from a pure OO approach - and I'm really trying hard not to slip into a procedural way of thinking, which is more my background.

I'm vaguely aware of JSON and NOSQL databases but not enough to know whether they are the solution to my problem. So, given all of this, I would really appreciate any views on the best way to keep things OO whilst at the same time having a client/server model allowing shared access to the application's data. I'm sure there's an easy solution - I'm just struggling to find it!

Any tips/thoughts?

Comment: you can do oop it in php too: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: Thanks Luiggi that's a thought but it doesn't address the question of how the objects should be communicated from the front end to the back nor how to store and subsequently reference them in a database of some description...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you seem to be thinking that OO and RDBMS' can't be a good match. They can be a good match IF you setup your schemas correctly.  There's far to little info to go on here, but often a single java-class to a single db-table can be a good start. That's the java to RDBMS part.

Communicating from your application-server to the client has nothing to do with this part (I'm saying because you seem to be suggesting it has?)

Having said that, NOSQL can be a good approach for having less restrictive schema's and (you're right here) often map more intuitively to objects as you would envision them in a oo-world. As for suggestions, I'm using MongoDB and it's great .. Also at this point JSON comes around the corner as the data-format to communicate with MongoDB.

All these technologies can be rather overwhelming if you're starting out, so instead of me advising you to pick A or B, perhaps it's better to checkout some good java web-frameworks that abstract away from persistence implementations so you can swap them out later without much problems? (Say Mysql for MongoDB, etc. )

I can highly recommend the Play Framework (http://www.playframework.org/) which gets you going pretty quickly and intuitively. Follow along the examples (they bolg a blog step by step including persistence, etc. ) and you get introduced nicely to the concepts.

Perhaps later you can check out plugins to use MongoDb instead of 1 of the default RDBMS's that come with Pplay, to see what you prefer.

Hth, 
Geert-Jan

Comment: Thanks Geert-Jan that is a great help! Were I to go with the Java Applet<->PHP<->MySQL route with the one to one mapping between classes and tables you suggest would I be right in thinking that I would need to serialise the objects (using JSON?) in order to pass them between the database and the applet?

Comment: ok I partially misread your question. You're talking about a java applet (indeed a client-side technology, albeit really not that common  anymore...) I was mistaking that with your intent of having a webframework (the server-side) in java. I'm afraid I have never developed a java applet but the communication tech would be the same: Doing a Http-post from java applet to PHP with your user-data serialized in the body. Indeed, Json is a good choice for that. ... Just curious, why do you want to develop a java applet? Perhaps there are better ways to go about it

Comment: 1-to-1 mapping would be, say, 1 user-table mapping against a user-class in Php. An instance of that user class would be serialized to Json  and communicated back and forth to the java applet (client). I'm not saying that that 1-to-1 is necessarily the best way to go, but this is the general routing.. So in other words, the java applet and the rdbms never (ever!) talk to eachother directlyfor security concerns, but also so that the java applet doesn't need to care how the app-server (php in this case does the persisting: i.e: it only cares how php serializes the object.

Comment: I'm intentionally going with the applet route because I'm trying to be very Java orientated at the moment to get some concrete practice in for all of the reading I've been doing. I know it's not the 'best' client side choice for this and frankly I could achieve this very much more easily just using HTML/PHP/MySQL but I'm being bloody minded :)

Comment: Well in that case, why not throw PHP out of the window and have a proper java webframework server-side instead? That should get you your java practice. Seriously, just follow the playframework example where they create a blog. That includes user-editing through the front-end, etc. so it's conceptually identical to what you want to accomplish (on a high level I admit) ..... and having had enought practice on the server-side, just get rid of those java-applet dinosaurs already  ... Just a friendly suggestion :)

Comment: Good advice - I'll definitely look into it! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

First be clear on your requirements and then try to determine what technologies suits your needs. You can look of capability into each datastore (MySQL, PostgreSQL etc) and see which one fits your requirements. Next look into [JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/) to query/manipulate the data in the database.

Comment: Thanks, I think my requirements are fairly clear - I'm stuck on the determination of technologies bit - hence the question :)

Comment: Fair Enough! You can start by looking into JSP/Servlets followed by JDBC and let us know if you get stuck anywhere.

Comment: Hmm, thank you again for this it looks like good advice, however, I neglected to mention that I'm a bit committed to PHP as the site into which I'm looking to integrate this is running on Drupal. My mistake for not mentioning this and again thanks for taking the time to post!